# Android build for Expo app failing due to unresolved dependencies

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I'm trying to publish my React Native Expo app to Google Play. I'm running the `eas build` command to try to create an android build, however every build attempt has failed, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Running "npm install" in the root dir of your repository 
[stderr] 
ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[stderr] 
npm ERR!
[stderr] 
npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/jest-native@5.4.1
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
[stderr] 
npm ERR! node_modules/react
[stderr] 
npm
[stderr] 
ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.8
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.8" from react-native-paper@5.2.0
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-paper
[stderr] 
npm ERR!       react-native-paper@"^5.2.0" from the root project
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   24 more (@react-native-firebase/app, @react-navigation/core, ...)

[stderr] 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[stderr] 
npm ERR! peer react-test-renderer@">=16.0.0" from @testing-library/jest-native@5.4.1
[stderr] 
npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/jest-native
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   dev @testing-library/jest-native@"^5.4.1" from the root project
[stderr] 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
[stderr] 
npm ERR! node_modules/react
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-test-renderer@18.2.0
[stderr] 
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-test-renderer
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     peer react-test-renderer@">=16.0.0" from @testing-library/jest-native@5.4.1
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/jest-native
[stderr] 
npm ERR!       dev @testing-library/jest-native@"^5.4.1" from the root project

[stderr] 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[stderr] 
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! See /home/expo/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
[stderr] 
[stderr] 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[stderr] 
npm ERR!     /home/expo/.npm/_logs/2023-02-22T06_54_51_705Z-debug-0.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
```

I'd normally try to problem solve this myself, but solving dependency clashes like this really goes beyond my experience - and using the command `--force, or --legacy-peer-deps` seems like it'll cause more problems. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here's my `package.json`, if that's any help:

```
{
  "name": "gig-fort",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/html-elements": "^0.2.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app-check": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.10",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^4.14.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.70.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "expo": "^47.0.12",
    "expo-application": "^5.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "^8.7.0",
    "expo-constants": "^14.0.2",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.0.1",
    "expo-device": "^5.0.0",
    "expo-font": "^11.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "^0.15.6",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "jest-expo": "^47.0.1",
    "lottie-react-native": "^5.1.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.3.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this happens because of dependency conflicts.
When trying to build the project it gets errors every time because by default it'll run `npm install` which is not working in that case.

So, you probably have to reinstall the packages with different versions which are supportable, or you can change the React's version in your project.

Comment: You might want to provide some details, e.g. why `npm install` won't work in the given case. References would also be helpful.